# Intent for activity brings another activity to front

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm creating an intent for a custom app shortcut like following:

```
Intent.ShortcutIconResource icon = ...;
Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getThis(), HandleShortcutActivity.class);
// add a few user settings
```

And the activity handles the intent like following:

```
public class HandleShortcutActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_helper);

        // get data from intent
        // ...
        // handle the action
        // ...

        // finish this activity instantly again
        finish();
    }
}
```

And here's my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".activities.HandleShortcutActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**Problem**

If `MainActivity` is runnning in background and my shortcut intent is started, my `MainActivity` is broought to front. Why? How can I avoid this?

Comment: why are you  finish(); your activity in onCreate()?

Comment: @MohdSaquib because the shortcut action is already handled and does not need any visual interface like an activity

Comment: the problem is with your manifest code remove  android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to set a 'Task Affinity' so that your task is created as a part of a new stack that is not related to your `MainActivity`. Then, when you `finish()` it, it would close the `HandleShortcutActivity` as opposed to going "back" to `MainActivity`

From the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff):-

> **android:taskAffinity**
>
> The task that the activity has an affinity for. Activities with the
>   same affinity conceptually belong to the same task (to the same
>   "application" from the user's perspective). The affinity of a task is
>   determined by the affinity of its root activity. The affinity
>   determines two things — the task that the activity is re-parented to
>   (see the allowTaskReparenting attribute) and the task that will house
>   the activity when it is launched with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
>
> By default, all activities in an application have the same affinity.
>   You can set this attribute to group them differently, and even place
>   activities defined in different applications within the same task. To
>   specify that the activity does not have an affinity for any task, set
>   it to an empty string.
>
> If this attribute is not set, the activity inherits the affinity set
>   for the application (see the  element's taskAffinity
>   attribute). The name of the default affinity for an application is the
>   package name set by the  element.

**HandleShortcutActivity** in your Manifest file after adding taskAffinity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.HandleShortcutActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity="">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

To explain what would happen in this case, see the below diagram with task #1 being your calling task/activity and task #2 being your `HandleShortcutActivity`

[image: Single Task Launch mode with Task Affinity Set]

I found [this article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) very useful when understanding the different Android Launch modes, and explains various scenarios you might face quite coherently.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:launchMode="singleTask"` from your `Activity` declaration in manifest file. 
this launch mode search `Activity` in task stack and if it's available takes from the stack and not created a new instance of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your manifest...

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```